# Tengo una columna en un DataFrame que contiene números enteros y cadena como puedo filtrarla?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtro

tengo una columna en un DataFrame de pandas que contiene numeros enteros y tambien cadenas con los numeros enteros se desea hacer un grafico.
Como hago este filtro por `dtype` o como elimino las cadenas.

Comment: Hola @cit9721. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Mediante `.apply()` puedes aplicar una función a todos los elementos de la columna, y puedes hacer que esa función detecte el tipo que te interesa. Por ejemplo:

```
def es_numero(dato):
    return type(dato) == int
```

Si tenemos el siguiente dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"datos": [
    3, 1, "2", 4, "cinco", 3, 5
]})
print(df)
```

---

```
   datos
0      3
1      1
2      2
3      4
4  cinco
5      3
6      5
```

Haciendo uso del `.apply()` obtendríamos una columna de booleanos, que nos dice qué elementos son enteros y cuáles no (observa que el elemento 2 es en realidad una cadena `"2"`):

```
df.datos.apply(es_numero)
```

---

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
```

Y esto podemos usarlo como filtro sobre el dataframe original:

```
print(df[df.datos.apply(es_numero)])
```

---

```
  datos
0     3
1     1
3     4
5     3
6     5
```

Dataframe sobre el que ya puedes hacer `.plot()`.

Entre los datos de la columna hemos metido un  `"2"` que ha desaparecido por ser una cadena, aunque en realidad era una cadena que representaba un entero, por lo que podría tener sentido incluirla también.

En este caso podríamos preparar otra función para aplicar, que intente convertir el dato en entero y retorne `None` si no pudo:

```
def como_entero(dato):
  try:
    dato = int(dato)
  except:
    dato = None
  return dato
```

Aplicando esta función el resultado sería ahora:

```
df.datos.apply(como_entero)
```

---

```
0    3.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
5    3.0
6    5.0
```

Vemos que en este caso el `"2"` fue convertido a `2.0`, mientras que el `"cinco"` quedó como `NaN`. Esto ya podrías graficarlo con `.plot()`, pero el inconveniente es que la gráfica te quedaría discontinua, pues la línea se interrumpe en cada `NaN`:

[image: Mal]

Si quieres evitarlo, puedes eliminar las filas que tengan `NaN` con un `dropna()`. O sea:

```
df.datos.apply(como_entero).dropna().plot()
```

[image: Bien]

Un detalle es que al eliminar filas, desaparecen también los valores correspondientes del índice del datframe. En este ejemplo, no habría dato para el índice `4`. Según tus necesidades podrías querer hacer un `reset_index(drop=True)` para volver a numerar los datos que sobrevivieron, de forma correlativa.